# jsPDF-AutoTable " doc.autoTable is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, jspdf, pdf.js, jspdf-autotable

I included the necessary links but it still gives me errors.
**error**

```
function pdfWrite() {
var doc = new jsPDF();
var columns = ["ID", "Name", "City"];
var rows = [
    [
        1, "Shaw", "Tanzania"
    ],
    [
        2, "Nelson", "Kazakhstan"
    ],
    [
        3, "Garcia", "Madagascar"
    ]
];

doc.autoTable(columns, rows)
doc.save('table.pdf');  
}
```

**working.**

```
<script>
var doc = new jsPDF();
var columns = ["Bina ID", "Bina Adı", "Özellik"];
  var rows = [
     [
    1, "Shaw", "Tanzania"
     ],
     [
      2, "Nelson", "Kazakhstan"
     ],
     [
    3, "Garcia", "Madagascar"
     ]
  ];
   doc.autoTable(columns, rows)
    doc.save('table.pdf'); 
   </script>
```

does not give an error when run on the index page. error when called with function in file

Comment: Your example code has multiple errors in it `scrip` instead of `script` and missing ending `}` for the `pdfWrite` function. Can you fix those issues first in your example so we can make sure that is not the issue?

Comment: I might have written wrongly when asking about the function question, but the code works only when the "doc.autoTable (columns, rows)" part fails. TYPEERROR: doc.autoTable is not a function

Comment: Yes, but it means that I can't run it and test it. Also it will probably be helped if you edited your question and added how you add the libraries (if you are using npm or cdn for example).

Comment: <script>
  function yazdir(){
   var data=<%-JSON.stringify(data) %>;
    var columns = ["ID", "Name", "Feature"];
    var rows=[];
    var i=0;
     data.forEach(function (item) {
     rows [i]= 
       [item.BDID,item.BDNM,item.NOTE] 
      
     i++;
     });     
     var doc = new jsPDF();
     doc.autoTable(columns, rows)
doc.save('table.pdf');
    }
</script>

Comment: this code works but in the separate js file it gives the specified error in the function.

Comment: I tried to install it with npm but it gave an error

Comment: Can you update the question with complete code that doesn't work? Preferably with the code snippet that can be run. Preferably also as an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing jspdf-autotable? Should look something like this:

```
let jsPDF = require('jspdf');
require('jspdf-autotable');
```

Comment: Module name "jspdf" has not been loaded yet for context